# How to get values from a templateFiled in GridView in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an assignment and I have a GridView that uses an SQL Datasourse.

The GridView has 2 columns, 1. name and 2. LastNmae. now I want to add one more column

which this column does not exist in the database. What I did is add a TemplateField

and I edited it and added DropDownList for the user to select an age.

The question is how can I get the value from what the user chooses from the DropDownList?

for exaple, if I want to get what is the first name, I would do this

```
GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

how can I do for the DropDownList?
Please help, thanks!

Comment: refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53559/Accessing-a-DropDownList-inside-a-GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
DropDownList dll = (DropDownList)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer.FindControl("ddPStatud");
String selectedValue = dll.SelectedValue;
```

and Use also.

```
string city = (gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlCities") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
```